# Limit area of screen for swipe gesture detection

Tags: android, gesture

I am using gesture detection to swipe between HUD views containing objects like seekbars overlaid on my app screen.

Is there a way to limit or set a portion of the screen to listen for detect gestures.

I am using a Custom ViewPager that looks like this.

main class.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
static GLSurfaceView mView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mView = (GLSurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.glview);


    mView.setZOrderOnTop(false);
    mView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
    mView.setRenderer(new GLLayer(this));
    mView.setDebugFlags(GLSurfaceView.DEBUG_CHECK_GL_ERROR);
    mView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY); // use with  mView.requestRender() for each user change


    // Create and set adapter
    CustomPagerAdapter adapter = new CustomPagerAdapter();
    ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.customviewpager);
    myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    myPager.setCurrentItem(0);

    // Add page change listener to pager component
    myPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new CustomPageChangeListener(this));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

customPageChangeListener

```
public class CustomPageChangeListener implements OnPageChangeListener, OnClickListener {

private Button buttonBlue   =   null;
private Button buttonYellow  =   null;
private Button buttonRed    =   null;
private ColorPicker colorPicker;

private Activity context    =   null;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public CustomPageChangeListener(Activity context) {
    this.context = context;
}


@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0 : {
            buttonBlue = (Button) context.findViewById(R.id.buttonBlue);
            buttonBlue.setOnClickListener(this);
            colorPicker = (ColorPicker) context.findViewById(R.id.colorPicker1);
            // other controls
            break;
        }
        case 1 : {
            buttonYellow = (Button) context.findViewById(R.id.buttonYellow);
            buttonYellow.setOnClickListener(this);
                    //other controls
            break;
        }
        case 2 : {
            buttonRed = (Button) context.findViewById(R.id.buttonRed);
            buttonRed.setOnClickListener(this);
                    // other controls
            break;
        }
    }   
}
```

and the adapter...

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

public Object instantiateItem(final View collection, int position) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    int resId = 0;
    switch (position) {
    case 0: {
        resId = R.layout.page_1;
        break;
    }
    case 1: {
        resId = R.layout.page_2;
        break;
    }
    case 2: {
        resId = R.layout.page_3;
        break;
    }
    }

    View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);



    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
    ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    return arg0 == ((View) arg1);

}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: And where gesture detection?

Comment: Im not sure but it works without any mention of gesture detection in the code. Does ViewPager just assume its being used?I just added the main activity class as well.

Answer (score 3):

First idea.

Try to watch your x and y value :

```
x = event.getX();
y = event.getY();
```

cut gestures on 100px on horisontaly:

```
if(x>100) return false;
else
    return viewPager.onTouchEvent(event);
```

Comment: thanks R.id.pandacoder. As noted above it is strange that the code has no reference to motion detection. Does viewPager naturally assume gestures? If so where would i place your code above?

Comment: Override onTouchEvent of viewPager and use my example

Comment: Thanks R.id.pandacoder. I understand your example above, thanks, but unfortunately I dont understand how to implement this into my example as there are no existing motion or onTouch events. Help appreciated. thanks.

Comment: I write to you tomorrow.

Comment: Hi R.id.pandacoder , any chance I could get your assistance with this?